# Why are some associated Legendre functions not orthogonal to each other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, spherical-harmonics, special-functions

For example, $P_1^1 = sin\theta$ and $P_2^2 = 3 sin^2\theta$ seem to be not orthogonal to each other because the integral
$$\int_0^\pi (sin\theta)(3 sin^2\theta) sin\theta d\theta$$
is not zero. Am I missing something? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are expecting an orthogonality relation that doesn’t hold. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials#Orthogonality for the two relations that do hold. See how the two functions have to have the same $l$ or the same $m$?

Comment: normally we treat the associated legendre functions as polynomials that satisfies $\int_{-1}^1P^m_aP^m_b=C(m,a)\delta_{a,b}$

Comment: There is no reason to expect them to be orthogonal - they're solutions of different Sturm-Liouville problems, and there is no direct relation between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the orthogonality is supplied by the azimuthal direction when  the two $z$-components of the angular momentum differ. This is why we usually bundle them together into the [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) instead of handling them separately.